# Como usar um ícone do font-awesome com botão do Material Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, font-awesome

Na Documentação do [Material Angular](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button) há exemplos de como usar ícones em botões, através de um ícone SVG.

Exemplo:

```
  <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" aria-label="Settings">
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
  </md-button>
```

Porém eu gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de usar ícones de fontes também. No meu caso estou utilizando o [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/).

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não me lembro de ter visto nada a respeito disso na documentação, mas para usar uma fonte como ícone, você precisa usar a diretiva `md-icon` com o a propriedade `md-font-icon` contendo a classe referente ao ícone (no seu caso os ícones do Font Awesome).

Veja:

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button">
    <md-icon md-font-icon="fa fa-edit"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```